# how do I define an emacs replace-regex shortcut command?

Tags: regex, emacs

I don't understand how to re-use an interactive command in a command I'm writing myself.

I want to make a command that always uses the same arguments to `replace-regexp`. It's a shortcut, really.

So I tried to mimic in a function what I'd done interactively on a selected region, namely:

```
M-x replace-regexp  RET ^\(\s *\)\(.*\)\s *$  RET  \1 + '\2'
```

I mimicked it by writing this function:

```
(defun myH2js ()
  "Converts html to an (incomplete) JavaScript String concatenation."

  (interactive)
  (let (p1 p2)
    (setq p1 "^\(\s *\)\(.*\)\s *$" )
    (setq p2 "\1 + '\2'" )
    (replace-regexp  p1 p2 )
  )
)
```

But my function "replaces zero occurrences" of the selected region whereas my interaction rewrites everything  exactly as I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex replacement with Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060723/regex-replacement-with-emacs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to double the backslashes in the strings, because backslash is both the string and regular expression escape character:

```
(defun myH2js (start end)
  "Converts html to an (incomplete) JavaScript String concatenation."

  (interactive "r")
  (let ((p1 "^\\(\\s *\\)\\(.*\\)\\s *$")
        (p2 "\\1 + '\\2'"))
    (replace-regexp p1 p2 nil start end)
  )
)
```

Note that `replace-regexp` is not recommended for use inside programs; the online documentation says:

> This function is usually the wrong thing to use in a Lisp program.
>   What you probably want is a loop like this:
>
> ```
>   (while (re-search-forward regexp nil t)
>     (replace-match to-string nil nil))
> ```
>
> which will run faster and will not set the mark or print anything.

Comment: He notes in the question that he uses this interactively on a region, you'll need to add start and end parameters to the function, and use (interactive "r") to support the same behavior

Comment: Thanks @Barmar and @Jordon Biondo. I've also learnt from this that the `start` and `end` parameters are automagically provided as long as there's a valid region selected.

Comment: A little tip I discovered: by adding `(message "p1 is %s." p1)` to the let block you can see any errors in your escape-slashing in the *Message* buffer where Emacs prints the "unescaped" / "original" / more-easily-debugged version of your regexp.