# Want to replace the underscore and following char with uppercase char in emacs lisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to replace the String abcd_efg to abcdEfg using emacs lisp. For some reason the following doesn't work

```
 (replace-regexp-in-string "_\(.\)" "\,(capitalize \1) "abcd_efg")
```

but works when i do

```
 M-x replace-regexp _\(.\) \,(capitalize \1)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex replacement with Emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060723/regex-replacement-with-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `\` is an escape character in elisp strings. So, if you want to create a regexp containing a backslash, you will have to write `\\`.

Secondly, the `\,` construct is not available when calling the function.

```
(let ((s "abc_def_ghi_2_")
      (pos 0))
  (while (string-match "_\\(.\\)" s pos)
    (setq pos (match-end 0))
    (setq s (replace-match (capitalize (match-string 1 s)) nil nil s 1)))
  s)
```

This returns:

```
"abc_Def_Ghi_2_"
```